# Material UI Autocomplete - warning: A props object containing a "key" prop is being spread into JSX

Tags: material-ui

So I am using the Material UI Autocomplete component with Next.js, and receiving this warning that I tried to resolve but could not.  Is the error from renderInput function? If so there is no "key" property in "...params" , so I can not remove like the warning message suggest.

How I can fix this?

```
const top100Films = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

// props.tags = ['a', 'c']

<Autocomplete
  multiple
  id="tags-outlined"
  onChange={(event: any, newValue: string[]) => {
    props.onTagsChange(newValue);
  }}
  options={top100Films}
  value={props.tags}
  filterSelectedOptions
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField
      {...params}
      label="Tags"
      placeholder="Tag"
    />
  )}
/>
```

[image]

```
hydration-error-info.js?32aa:26 Warning: A props object containing a "key" prop is being spread into JSX:
  let props = {key: someKey, tabIndex: ..., role: ..., id: ..., onMouseOver: ..., onClick: ..., onTouchStart: ..., data-option-index: ..., aria-disabled: ..., aria-selected: ..., className: ..., children: ...};
  <li {...props} />
React keys must be passed directly to JSX without using spread:
  let props = {tabIndex: ..., role: ..., id: ..., onMouseOver: ..., onClick: ..., onTouchStart: ..., data-option-index: ..., aria-disabled: ..., aria-selected: ..., className: ..., children: ...};
  <li key={someKey} {...props} />
```

Comment: I was able to use the hints given by minchaej below to fix this. @mickael

Comment: Ok thank you, I didn’t like the solution because in another project I don’t have to write all this code in order to make the autocomplete work. But if it solves the problem I’ll try it. Yout should mark his response as solution.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The problem is due to how nextjs renders its components. Specifically, it is due to improper `key` setting for the list of options and tags in `Autocomplete` component. Although it is quite tedious, you have to explicitly state the keys of tags and options using below.

You could use `renderOption` and `renderTags` provided by `Autocomplete` to fix this issue.

```
  renderOption={(props, option) => {
    return (
      <li {...props} key={option}>
        {option.label}
      </li>
    );
  }}
```

And

```
    renderTags={(tagValue, getTagProps) => {
      return tagValue.map((option, index) => (
        <Chip {...getTagProps({ index })} key={option} label={option} />
      ))
    }}
```

So... in your case it would become:

```
  <Autocomplete
    multiple
    id="tags-outlined"
    options={top100Films}
    onChange={(event: any, newValue: string[]) => {
      props.onTagsChange(newValue);
    }}
    value={props.tags}
    filterSelectedOptions
    renderOption={(props, option) => {
      return (
        <li {...props} key={option}>
          {option}
        </li>
      )
    }}
    renderTags={(tagValue, getTagProps) => {
      return tagValue.map((option, index) => (
        <Chip {...getTagProps({ index })} key={option} label={option} />
      ))
    }}
    renderInput={(params) => (
      <TextField
        {...params}
        label="Tags"
        placeholder="Tag"
      />
    )}
  />
```

You could read more about `renderOption` and `renderTags` [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/autocomplete/).

PS. Don't forget to import `Chip` from Mui!

Comment: meaning you must set renderTags as well as renderOption, or the error won't fade away

Comment: Thanks. But the warning is not worth the effort of fixing it. I'd rather put up with it until the bug is fixed in next

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution:

```html
<ReactSlider
   className='horizontal-slider'
   thumbClassName='price-thumb'
   trackClassName='price-track'
   defaultValue={[0, 100]}
   renderThumb={(props, state) => {
     const { key, ...restProps } = props;
     const prop = { ...restProps };
     return (
       <div key={key} {...prop} className='relative'>
         <p className='absolute left-[-1rem] bottom-6'>
            {state.valueNow}
         </p>
       </div>
     );
   }}
/>
```

Answer (score -5):

You are passing props in Textfield tag like this

```
<TextField
  {...params}
  label="Tags"
  placeholder="Tag"
/>
```

Try with passing props in Textfield tag like this

```
 <TextField
      props={params}
      label="Tags"
      placeholder="Tag"
    />
```