# Next.js Material UI useAutoComplete - Warning: A props object containing a "key" prop is being spread into JSX

Tags: next.js, material-ui

I am trying to use the existing code(Customized hook) given at the [mui doc](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#customized-hook):

```
<Root>
  <div {...getRootProps()}>
    <Label {...getInputLabelProps()}>Tags</Label>
    <InputWrapper
      ref={setAnchorEl}
      className={focused ? "focused" : ""}
    >
      {value.map((tag: string, index: number) => (
        <StyledTag key={tag} label={tag} {...getTagProps({ index })} />
      ))}
      <input {...getInputProps()} />
    </InputWrapper>
  </div>
  {groupedOptions.length > 0 ? (
    <Listbox {...getListboxProps()}>
      {(groupedOptions as typeof tags).map((option, index) => (
        <li key={index} {...getOptionProps({ option, index })}>
          <span>{option}</span>
          <CheckIcon fontSize="small" />
        </li>
      ))}
    </Listbox>
  ) : null}
</Root>
```

First, I get the warning of missing key prop. After I insert `key={index}` inside the `<li>` like this: `<li key={index} {...getOptionProps({ option, index })}>`. I get the following new warning after clicking the input search bar:

[image: Warning]

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reaching out, here is the solution.

The problem is due to how nextjs renders its components. Long story short, it is due to improper `key` setting for the elements created from iteration in Autocomplete component. Although it is quite tedious, you have to explicitly state the **UNIQUE** keys for all elements (including all the child elements as well).

This problem is a little variation of the problem I resolved in this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75818761/material-ui-autocomplete-warning-a-props-object-containing-a-key-prop-is-be). The only difference is that, this time, the iterated elements have nested elements.

For example,

```
      // This has nested elements
      {(groupedOptions as typeof top100Films).map((option, index) => (
        <li {...getOptionProps({ option, index })} key={index}>
          <span key={index + 1000}>{option.title}</span>
          <CheckIcon fontSize="small" key={index + 2000} />
        </li>
      ))}
```

While this has no nested elements,

```
      {(groupedOptions as typeof top100Films).map((option, index) => (
        <li {...getOptionProps({ option, index })} key={index}>
            {option.title}
        </li>
      ))}
```

If you had no nested elements, my previous solution would be sufficient, where you set keys to the top elements only. Like I said, all elements should have keys and all keys should be unique. So notice how I made a 'dummy' unique key by adding 1000 or 2000? You should implement a logic to generate unique keys, so solely using index is not sufficient, as the child elements need a way to get unique keys.

In addition, you should always place `key={index}` after the spread such as `{...getOptionProps({ option, index })}` so that it looks like `<li {...getOptionProps({ option, index })} key={index}>`. This is so that the newly set keys will override the keys set by the spread.

**TLDR**: So to solve your problem

1. Place keys properly (specifically after the spread)
2. Place keys to ALL elements in the iteration (such as child elements)

Here is the complete code to your problem. Focus on the changes that I made and the comments. Copy paste it on your local machine and run it, it works. Please let me know if you have any more questions.

```html
'use client'

import * as React from 'react'
import useAutocomplete, {
  AutocompleteGetTagProps,
} from '@mui/base/useAutocomplete'
import CheckIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Check'
import CloseIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Close'
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles'
import { autocompleteClasses } from '@mui/material/Autocomplete'

const Root = styled('div')(
  ({ theme }) => `
  color: ${
    theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? 'rgba(255,255,255,0.65)' : 'rgba(0,0,0,.85)'
  };
  font-size: 14px;
`
)

const Label = styled('label')`
  padding: 0 0 4px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  display: block;
`

const InputWrapper = styled('div')(
  ({ theme }) => `
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid ${theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? '#434343' : '#d9d9d9'};
  background-color: ${theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? '#141414' : '#fff'};
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 1px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  &:hover {
    border-color: ${theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? '#177ddc' : '#40a9ff'};
  }

  &.focused {
    border-color: ${theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? '#177ddc' : '#40a9ff'};
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(24, 144, 255, 0.2);
  }

  & input {
    background-color: ${theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? '#141414' : '#fff'};
    color: ${
      theme.palette.mode === 'dark'
        ? 'rgba(255,255,255,0.65)'
        : 'rgba(0,0,0,.85)'
    };
    height: 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 4px 6px;
    width: 0;
    min-width: 30px;
    flex-grow: 1;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
  }
`
)

interface TagProps extends ReturnType<AutocompleteGetTagProps> {
  index: number // Get index to implement a unique key
  label: string
}

function Tag(props: TagProps) {
  const { label, onDelete, index, ...other } = props // Get index to implement a unique key
  return (
    // Place unique key to all elements
    <div {...other} key={index}>
      <span key={props.key + 3000}>{label}</span>
      <CloseIcon onClick={onDelete} key={index + 1000} />
    </div>
  )
}

const StyledTag = styled(Tag)<TagProps>(
  ({ theme }) => `
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 24px;
  margin: 2px;
  line-height: 22px;
  background-color: ${
    theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? 'rgba(255,255,255,0.08)' : '#fafafa'
  };
  border: 1px solid ${theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? '#303030' : '#e8e8e8'};
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding: 0 4px 0 10px;
  outline: 0;
  overflow: hidden;

  &:focus {
    border-color: ${theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? '#177ddc' : '#40a9ff'};
    background-color: ${theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? '#003b57' : '#e6f7ff'};
  }

  & span {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }

  & svg {
    font-size: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 4px;
  }
`
)

const Listbox = styled('ul')(
  ({ theme }) => `
  width: 300px;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: ${theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? '#141414' : '#fff'};
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 250px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  z-index: 1;

  & li {
    padding: 5px 12px;
    display: flex;

    & span {
      flex-grow: 1;
    }

    & svg {
      color: transparent;
    }
  }

  & li[aria-selected='true'] {
    background-color: ${theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? '#2b2b2b' : '#fafafa'};
    font-weight: 600;

    & svg {
      color: #1890ff;
    }
  }

  & li.${autocompleteClasses.focused} {
    background-color: ${theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? '#003b57' : '#e6f7ff'};
    cursor: pointer;

    & svg {
      color: currentColor;
    }
  }
`
)

export default function CustomizedHook() {
  const {
    getRootProps,
    getInputLabelProps,
    getInputProps,
    getTagProps,
    getListboxProps,
    getOptionProps,
    groupedOptions,
    value,
    focused,
    setAnchorEl,
  } = useAutocomplete({
    id: 'customized-hook-demo',
    defaultValue: [top100Films[1]],
    multiple: true,
    options: top100Films,
    getOptionLabel: (option) => option.title,
  })

  return (
    <Root>
      <div {...getRootProps()}>
        <Label {...getInputLabelProps()}>Customized hook</Label>
        <InputWrapper ref={setAnchorEl} className={focused ? 'focused' : ''}>
          {value.map((option: FilmOptionType, index: number) => (
            // Place unique key to all elements
            <StyledTag
              label={option.title}
              {...getTagProps({ index })}
              key={index}
              index={index}
            />
          ))}
          <input {...getInputProps()} />
        </InputWrapper>
      </div>
      {groupedOptions.length > 0 ? (
        <Listbox {...getListboxProps()}>
          {(groupedOptions as typeof top100Films).map((option, index) => (
            // Place unique key to all elements
            <li {...getOptionProps({ option, index })} key={index}>
              <span key={index + 1000}>{option.title}</span>
              <CheckIcon fontSize="small" key={index + 2000} />
            </li>
          ))}
        </Listbox>
      ) : null}
    </Root>
  )
}

interface FilmOptionType {
  title: string
  year: number
}

// Top 100 films as rated by IMDb users. http://www.imdb.com/chart/top
const top100Films = [
  { title: 'The Shawshank Redemption', year: 1994 },
  { title: 'The Godfather', year: 1972 },
  { title: 'The Godfather: Part II', year: 1974 },
  // ...
]
```