# Autocomplete MUI is warning that I need a key for each child passed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using the Autocomplete component from MUI and am running into an issue where I am getting this warning:
*Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.*

I've already added keys to both renderOption and renderTags, but am still getting the warning message.

It is not breaking my code, but I like to keep warnings down to a minimum because usually they do start breaking things in production.

Please let me know any suggestions you have.

I've added keys to both renderOption and renderTags below and still get the error.

I tried the checked solution and the one below it from
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75818761/material-ui-autocomplete-warning-a-props-object-containing-a-key-prop-is-be) but it did not seem to make a difference.

Here is my code:

```
<Autocomplete
 multiple
 limitTags={2}
 options={allMeetings}
 getOptionLabel={(option)=>option.title}
 renderOption={(props, option)=>{
     const { key, ...restProps} = props;
     return (
         <li {...restProps} key={option.meetingId+key} style={{flexDirection: "column",         justifyContent: "flex-start"}}> 
         <Typography variant='subtitle1'>{option.title}</Typography>
         <Typography variant='caption'>{option.date}&nbsp;-&nbsp;{option.startTime}</Typography>
         </li>)
         }}
 renderTags={(tagValue, getTagProps)=> {
    return tagValue.map((option, index)=>{
         const {key, ...restProps} = getTagProps({index});
          return <Chip {...restProps} key={key} label={option.title} />
     })
  }}
 renderInput={(params, index)=> {
     return <TextField 
            {...params}
            label="Meetings"/>
  }}/>
```

allMeetings is an object i am passing that has title, meetingId, start and endtime, and date.

key that I am getting from props is the title of the meeting object

in my db I am sure that meetingIds are unique and not duplicating.

For reference I've attached what logs in the console when I add a console.log(option) within renderOption. meetingId starts at meeting and continues as meeting-1, meeting-2, etc.
[image: meeting object that is being passed through autocomplete]

Edit:
This is what I get when I console.log(getTagProps({index})
[image: getTagProps console.log]

I made a change to Chip changing key={key} to key={option.meetingId+key}
and am still getting an error. (Although key seems to just change depending on the amount of items made as keys, 0,1,2,etc.)

Edit (2):
Here is a screenshot of my keys that are being used in renderOptions:
[image: renderOption screenshots]

Here is a screenshot of my keys that are being used in renderTags:

[image: renderTags screenshots]

I changed the key for renderTags to {option.meetingId+"-"+key}
because I could see how without the dash I would run into this same issue in the future. But I am still getting the key prop warning.

Comment: The problem is not evident from the details you've provided (at least not to me). Most probably, the `key` value set to the `Chip` components are the same (this seems to be dependent on what `getTagProps({index})` returns and that is not evident).

Comment: @Titus Ive edited my question to include what getTagProps console.logs

Comment: Let me know if there is any more detail i can give here.

Comment: The warning suggests that your keys are not unique. So either `key={option.meetingId+key}` in `renderOption` does not produce unique keys. Or `key={key}` in `renderTags` does not produce unique keys. My guess guess would be on that latter. That should probably also be `key={option.meetingId+key}`.

Comment: @3limin4t0r ive added screenshots of what they are currently outputting. And made a change to renderTags key value because I would run into this same issue when I have more meetings added, but I am still getting the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched the key and {...restProps} in renderOption and now the warning is gone

how embarrasing >.<

```
<Autocomplete
 multiple
 limitTags={2}
 options={allMeetings}
 getOptionLabel={(option)=>option.title}
 renderOption={(props, option)=>{
     const { key, ...restProps} = props;
     return (
         <li key={option.meetingId+'-'+key} {...restProps} style={{flexDirection: "column", justifyContent: "flex-start"}}> 
         <Typography variant='subtitle1'>{option.title}</Typography>
         <Typography variant='caption'>{option.date}&nbsp;-&nbsp;{option.startTime}</Typography>
         </li>)
         }}
 renderTags={(tagValue, getTagProps)=> {
    return tagValue.map((option, index)=>{
         const {key, ...restProps} = getTagProps({index});
          return <Chip {...restProps} key={option.meetingId+"-"+key} label={option.title} />
     })
  }}
 renderInput={(params, index)=> {
     return <TextField 
            {...params}
            label="Meetings"/>
  }}/>
```

Comment: You are doing great by minimizing the warnings at start, below is the video for your motivation on how the Key prop caused my production application to malfunction :) .


https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z7UY2NgBLUo