# Material UI Autocomplete and Next.js 14.0.4 - Warning: A props object containing a "key" prop is being spread into JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, material-ui

```js
'use client';

import { Autocomplete, TextField } from '@mui/material';

export default function Combobox({ id, label, options, ...props }) {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id={id}
      options={options}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label={label} placeholder={label} />}
      {...props}
    />
  );
}
```

```js
'use client';

import Combobox from '@/components/Forms/Combobox';

import { Paper, Grid } from '@mui/material';

const comboBoxOptions = [
  {
    id: 1,
    label: 'Lorem ipsum dolor',
    value: 'lorem'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    label: 'Sit amet consectetur',
    value: 'sit'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    label: 'Adipisicing elit',
    value: 'adipisicing'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    label: 'Sed do eiusmod tempor',
    value: 'sed'
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    label: 'Incididunt ut labore et dolore',
    value: 'incididunt'
  }
];

export default function FormsPage() {
  return (
    <Paper
      sx={{
        p: 2
      }}
      elevation={3}
    >
      <h1>Form Item Examples</h1>
      <Grid container spacing={2} rowSpacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={12} md={3}>
          <Combobox id="simple-smart-select" options={comboBoxOptions} label="Smart Select" fullWidth />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} md={3}>
          <Combobox
            multiple
            id="multiple-smart-select"
            options={comboBoxOptions}
            label="Multiple Smart Select"
            fullWidth
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Paper>
  );
}
```

I am experimenting with how to use MUI components in my next.js 14.0.4 project. When I try to use the Autocomplete component with multiple features, I get an error like this when the page is rendered in the console;

```
MUI: A component is changing the default value state of an uncontrolled Autocomplete after being initialized. To suppress this warning opt to use a controlled Autocomplete.
```

Then there is no problem in the selection process, but when I start to make a selection, an error like this appears in my console;

```
Warning: A props object containing a "key" prop is being spread into JSX:
  let props = {key: someKey, label: ..., size: ..., className: ..., disabled: ..., data-tag-index: ..., tabIndex: ..., onDelete: ...};
  <ForwardRef(Chip) {...props} />
React keys must be passed directly to JSX without using spread:
  let props = {label: ..., size: ..., className: ..., disabled: ..., data-tag-index: ..., tabIndex: ..., onDelete: ...};
  <ForwardRef(Chip) key={someKey} {...props} />
```

What do I need to do to get rid of these errors, what could be the place I overlooked?

Comment: Could you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75818761/material-ui-autocomplete-warning-a-props-object-containing-a-key-prop-is-be?rq=2